# What is the use of Hashable and Equatable in Swift? When to use which?

Tags: swift

I know that Hashable is inherited from Equatable, but can you give me an example that requires Hashable, not just Equatable. Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to hear more about the _performance_ difference when iterating large arrays between Hashable and Equatable, as this should factor into the decision of whether an object should be Hashable or not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you conform to `Hashable`, you provide a method that returns the *hash value* of `self`.

When you conform to `Equatable`, you provide a method that returns whether the given object and `self` are equal.

They seem to serve two very different purposes, why does `Hashable` inherit `Equatable`? Because the hash values for two equal objects are equal!

What can and can't you do with `Hashable` and `Equatable`?

`Equatable` has more limited uses than `Hashable`. It can only compare the equality of two objects, and that's it.

For `Hashable`, because you can get a number that represents the object, you can kind of *treat the objects as numbers*. You can compare the objects: whether it is less than, greater than, or equal to another object, just like you do with numbers:

```
if objA.hashValue > objB.hashValue
```

This also means you can sort objects with `Hashable`.

 (Sorry, I wrote this part when I was young and ignorant)

Last but not least, you can use `Hashable` objects as keys for dictionaries. They make use of the hash code to make looking up values more efficient.

Comment: I don't know swift, but the odds that `Hashable` was intended for sorting is nearly nil. It's usually for use with hash tables/dictionaries which are unordered. Usually there is a `Comparable` interface for actually making sortable types; sorting on hash codes is consistent, but meaningless in most cases.

Comment: And, yeah, looks like Swift [has a `dictionary` type](http://docs.elementscompiler.com/API/StandardTypes/DictionarySwift/), which is what `Hashable` would be intended to work with.

Comment: @LeoDabus: Swift may let you do it, but it's pointless. Ordering by hashcode is rarely a meaningful ordering for any data that is not small enough to effectively self hash (an `int` may hash to itself, so sorting on hash code is meaningful there, but for strings, and other high level objects, it may be consistent, but it's 100% arbitrary).

Comment: I also don't think Hashable is invented for sorting. But why is it there? In Swift Dictionary keys must conform to Hashable. Why is it so? Since to disallow duplicates, it seems Equatable is enough to do so. Why the system will prefer (and requires) to use Hashable?

Comment: @HuangChao: Read up on [Hash Tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table); `Dictionary` is based on them. The idea is that by using hashing, you can turn membership testing, retrieval and deletion into (roughly) fixed cost operations (in big-O notation, `O(1)`), where the same operation on a normal sequence would require a linear scan of every element (`O(n)`). If you've got 10,000 elements, performing 10,000 equality checks to figure out the needle isn't in the haystack is going to get expensive; hash tables can reduce that to a handful of tests in most cases.

Comment: Also, comparing hashes (ints) should be faster than comparing dictionary keys (strings) when searching, etc.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you very much!

Answer (score 19):

You could use `hashValue` to determine if two objects are ***not*** equal to each other.

Apart from that, you *shouldn't* make any `Equatable` or `Comparable` determination of an object solely based on the object's hash value.

In short, `Hashable` is derived from `Equatable` because you can't safely determine if two objects are equal to each other merely by testing their `hashValue` for equality.

**Further details**

Per the [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html):

> A hash value is an Int value that is the same for all objects that compare equally, such that if `a == b`, it follows that `a.hashValue == b.hashValue`.

However, the inverse is not true.  If `a.hashValue == b.hashValue`, it does ***not*** follow that `a == b`.

While there are perfect hash functions that return `unique` values, a hash function could return the same `hashValue` for two or more different objects. This is known as a *hash collision*.

**Avoid trying to do this**

[Sweeper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34916094/4151918) says:

> For Hashable, because you can get a number that represents the object, you can kind of treat the objects as numbers. You can compare the objects: whether it is less than, greater than, or equal to another object, just like you do with numbers:

No. What you're comparing are the hash values of the (possibly collided) objects, *not* the objects themselves.

- Comparing whether a hash value is less than or greater than another hash value is meaningless with respect to the object.
- In regard to equality, it would only hold true *if* a hash function returned a perfectly unique value for the object.

`Hashable` itself has very limited use, apart from `Equatable`. For safety, you should always test the objects themselves.

Comment: What about the case where you have two objects that ARE equal by == but their hash values are not equal.  For example, you have a dictionary of objects where every instance should be considered different if the ObjectIdentifier is different when in a dictionary. But, otherwise the same if all values are the same. (This is for class instances)  What then?

Comment: is what you're saying about the level of hash collision still true with the introduction of `Hasher`?

Answer (score 1):

To understand the difference between Hashable and Equitable, consider `NoOneModel` is a struct and it have two integers `x` and `y`

```
struct NoOneModel {
  var x = 0
  var y = 0
}
```

let's create a two instances `model1` and `model2`

```
let model1 = NoOneModel(x: 1, y: 1)
let model2 = NoOneModel(x: 1, y: 2) /// y value is different

print(model1 == model2) /// false
```

if we check model1 and model2 are equal? then it will return `false`, because `y` value is different in both models

let's confirm a `Hashable` protocol and combine `x` value, it indicates that `hashValue` will create only from `x`

```
extension NoOneModel: Hashable {
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(x)
    }
}
```

now check it's `HashValue` returns same for both models because we combine only `x` value and `x` value is `1` in both models

```
print(model1.hashValue == model2.hashValue) /// true
```

let's confirm `Equitable` protocol and implement `==` function.

```
extension NoOneModel: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: NoOneModel, rhs: NoOneModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.x == rhs.x
    }
}
```

now try to compare both models

```
print(model1 == model2) /// true
```

Here the `y` value of both models are different even if check for `==` condition it will return `true` because equitable protocol is included for only `x` value.

> Note: Hashable is inherited from Equitable, it indicates that we can
> add == directly without reconfirming the Equitable protocol

Hope this will helps to understand the difference between hashable and equitable protocols.
Thank you.

Comment: `print(model1 == model2) /// false` won't even run: the initial `struct NoOneModel {...}` doesn't specify that it be Equatable, so `==` isn't available.  It has to be: `struct NoOneModel: Equatable {...}` unless someone implements `==` directly.